# creating a readonly user on postgres hot standby server

Tags: postgresql, authentication, replication, roles

I have a slave postgres server running in hot standby mode. Currently there is DB owner role that I use to connect and query to this server. Now, I want to create another readonly user/role with a password that I can share to other users so that they can query this standby server. What I read from documentation is that since it's stand by server, I cannot create another user on the database. How do I solve this problem? How do I create another user with read only access?

Comment: You can't write on the slave anyway, so even if the user you are using has write _privileges_ on the master, there is no way to do any writing with that user on the slave.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a reporting database, by replicating the production database. For security and performance issues, I do not want to modify production database. Is there any other solution, than master-slave, to achieve this?

Comment: you can create a user that is only allowed to connect to the standby database but not to the master. This can be achieved through the configuration in `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 2):

The hot standby server is a exact copy of its master server. Thus, you can't create a user only on the hot standby server. But you may create a readonly user on the master server, which will be automatically copied to the hot standby server.